# Refactoring a try with resource in Java 11 that use different objects

Tags: java, refactoring

My code is becoming a little bit heavy and I would like to refactor my code and make it easier to maintain. I use 2 try catch with resources in 4 parts of my code and they really look like very similar.

My objective would be to call a service instead :

Here is the code block that is repeated :

```
try(OutputStream os = con.getOutputStream()) {
    byte[] input = jsonInputString.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
    os.write(input, 0, input.length);
}

try(BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream(), StandardCharsets.UTF_8))) {
    StringBuilder response = new StringBuilder();
    String responseLine;
    while ((responseLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
        response.append(responseLine.trim());
    }
    System.out.println(response.toString());
    returnValue = gson.fromJson(response.toString(), GetSourceFileRestResponseModel.class);
    System.out.println(returnValue);
}
```

My issue is that "returnValue" can be different kind of objects that are very different.

```
GetSourceFileRestResponseModel returnValue = new GetSourceFileRestResponseModel();
```

or

```
UpdateSourceFileRequestModel returnValue = new UpdateSourceFileRequestModel();
```

Apparently my objective is to enter an object and retrieve a string as result if i understand well the code i made :))

Answer (score 0):

Use Java Generics, for example, you define a class

```
public class GenericJson <T>{
public T returnJsnoValue(){
    T returnValue = null;
    try(BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream(), StandardCharsets.UTF_8))) {
        StringBuilder response = new StringBuilder();
        String responseLine;
        while ((responseLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
           response.append(responseLine.trim());
        }
        System.out.println(response.toString());
        returnValue = gson.fromJson(response.toString(),T.class);
        System.out.println(returnValue);
    }
  }
}
```

I don't know how the rest of your code looks like but update your question to be able to help you even more